# How to prevent popup from closing by outside the window click in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, popup

In my activity i'm opening a popup (alert dialog) with yes and no option. But when I click outside the window or anywhere in the screen the popup is dismissed. How can I prevent the popup from closing by clicking anywhere. I want that it should close when I enter No button only. Please help!!!

Here is the popup code in MainActivity.java

Handler handler = new Handler();

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override

    public void run() {


   if (context != null) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("Message")
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // continue with delete
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    });

            mDialog = alert.create();
            mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle;
            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing())
            mDialog.show();
            // .setIcon(R.drawable.inr1)
            // .show();

        }
    }
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Maybe  .setCancelable(false) to AlertDialog.Builder?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya where to use this command? Outside of Handler or just below the mDialog.show(); ???

Answer (score 1):

add this line before `mDialog.show();`

```
mDialog .setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
mDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `mDialog.setCancelable(true);`

Comment: OR mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Answer (score 0):

simply adding following line will solve your problem

```
mDialog .setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```