# Clicking outside "never show again" popup dialog

Tags: android, popup

I used the answer from Cengiz Can from here

> [How to make a "do not ask me again" dialog pop-up box? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550039/how-to-make-a-do-not-ask-me-again-dialog-pop-up-box-android/9550136)

to set up a "never show again" dialog popup. It works but when the user clicks outside of the popup dialog, it closes.

How can I block the user from clicking outside in order that my popup does not get closed.

The dialog just should get closed when the user clicks "cancel" or "Ok" and not by clicking outside the box anywhere in the layout.

Is there a method to avoid this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265120/how-to-prevent-popup-from-closing-by-outside-the-window-click-in-android?rq=1

Comment: The answer also inside the link you provided, `setCancelable(false);`

Comment: yeah, I have seen it, thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add set `builder.setCancelable(false);` in your dialog builder. it will not close user click on screen apart from button.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line `builder.setCancelable(false);`

**Example**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Test");
builder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid closing the dialog with the back key :

```
setCancelable(false);
```

If you want to avoid closing the dialog touching outside :

```
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```